# Incorrect calculation double

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, double

I have some C# application:

```
double n = p * q;
double S = Math.Pow(M, d) % n;
```

In my situation, M==7, d==27, n = 55. I calculate it in the Windows default calculator, and get 28. But my application returns 14. Why?

Comment: Break it out into separate steps, set a breakpoint and see what's going on under the hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double` has a maximum of 16 digits of precision, but `7^27` is a 23-digit number, so you are losing precision in the exponentiation.  Windows calculator supports 32 digits of precision for transcendental functions (like `pow`), so it can perform the calculation without a loss of precision.

You *could* use the mathematical fact that `(a^b) % N` is the same an `((a%n) ^ b) % n`, but you're *still* raining a number greater then 2 to the 27th power which can't be precisely represented in a `double`.

Another option is to split the power into multiple exponents that *can* be represented in a `double` without a loss of precision:

```
     7^27 = 7^9 * 7^9 * 7^9
7^27 % 55 = ((7^9) % 55 * (7^9) % 55 * (7^9) % 55) % 55
          = (52 * 52 * 52) % 55
          = 140,608 % 55
          = 28
```

Comment: [A calculator by Rick Regan](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/) says that `7^27 = 65712362363534280139543` will be converted to `65712362363534278918144`. Additionally, a lot of useful information about floating point numbers can be found on that site.

Answer (score 4):

As D Stanley mentioned, `double` only has 16 digits of precision. You need to use `BigInteger`. Which is in .NET 4.5 and 4.6. You'll need to add a reference to `System.Numerics`

```
BigInteger test = BigInteger.Pow(7, 27) % 55;
```

Comment: all is ok, but % can not be used for `BigInteger` and `double`.

Comment: @V.Panchenko Why can't you use the mod operator with `BigInteger`? It worked fine for me: http://imgur.com/vIqXINw